# Deleted migration files - Laravel

Tags: reference, migration, laravel

After creating the migration files for this test project I have created the models and controllers.

When trying to access the model from the controller Laravel was resolving the migration file class instead of the one in the models folder. Any method inside ContentController would reference class Content inside `/migrations/2013_06_13_123825_content.php` rather than `/models/Content.php`.

So, as a first dumb attempt I have removed the migration files since I have the database modeled outside Laravel and now I can't figure out how to fix this upcoming issue:

```
include(/var/www/html/laravel/app/database/migrations/2013_06_13_123825_content.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I have already removed the migration rows in the database but this issue persists.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run `composer dump-autoload`. That should fix it!